# Spring aop by annotation on controller method does not work

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop

**Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

**AOP**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

@Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
public Object aroundHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @MyAnnotation(value="hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

in above condition, my aop does not work... 
It works fine with other methods, which is not annotated by `@Controller`. 
And it works fine with aop expression and controller method.

Is it possible to use aop by annotation with controller method?

Comment: I kinda lost you here `It works fine with other methods, which is not annotated by @Controller` -  `And it works fine with aop expression and controller method`

Also can you post a bit more code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
public Object aroundHandler(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use @within...this blog post may help https://www.productiveprogrammer.net/?p=49